# Why the value does not pass to next TabbarViewController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

In one.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *carNumber = [self.carNumberArrayFromPlistFile objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *engineNumber  = [self.engineNumberArrayFromPlistFile objectAtIndex:row];
    CarInfo *oneCarInfo = [[CarInfo alloc] initWithCarNumber:carNumber engineNumber:engineNumber];
    Two *two = [[Two alloc] initWithNibName:@"Two" bundle:nil];
    two.car = oneCarInfo;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:two animated:YES];
    [oneCarInfo release];
    [two release];
}
```

In two.h

```
@interface Two : UITabBarController
{
    CarInfo *car;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)CarInfo *car;
```

And why the car in Two.m is always null? Please help me with this. Thank you guys!

Two.m:

```
@interface Two ()
@end

@implementation Two
@synthesize car;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.car = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you @synthesize car? Why are you inheriting from UITabBarController? Are you referencing car with `car` or `self.car`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I am pretty sure that I @synthesize car and referencing car not self.car

Comment: Could you post the code for the @synthesize. Just out of curiosity, what happens if you use `self.car` instead of `car`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas Of course , there's .m file

Comment: @Jxdwinter you are not supposed to **push** instance of `UITabBarController` onto the stack of `UINavigationController` - check the documentation.

Comment: @PeterPajchl HO....I see, thank you very much. I am such a fool. But how can I pass this value to the UITabBarController?

Comment: @PeterPajchl HO....I see, and Im such a fool. But I want to how can I do this? Pass the value to UITabBarController?

Comment: What if you just make `Two` inherit from `UIViewController` instead of `UITabBarController`?  Usually selecting from a table goes to a detail controller, not a different tab.

Comment: Thank you guys, answer the question and I will choose yours is the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PeterPajchl : you are not supposed to push instance of UITabBarController onto the stack of UINavigationController - check the documentation.